# How do I use the VS Code C++ extension's additionalSOLibSearchPath launch config property? Does it accept glob patterns?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb

I'm working on a code that has 2 parts, one being a shared library, the other not (and containing the main function).

When I want to launch the VSC debugguer, the main program can't find the `myProject.so` file.

I tried adding the path in the `.vscode/launch.json` configuration as follow :

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/example/bin/debug/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "environment": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/example/bin",
            "additionalSOLibSearchPath": "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            // ...
        }
    ]
}
```

But it seems from the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_additionalsolibsearchpath) that the `additionalSoLibSearchPath` setting is only for Windows, while it's not explicitly or directly mentionned. We can guess it because the few examples only use Window's paths.

How can I do this for Linux ?

Comment: the docs pretty clearly say "for GDB or LLDB". So I'm not convinced that it's only a Windows thing. In fact, given the name, I'd be less surprised if it was a UNIX-only thing.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs you linked](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_additionalsolibsearchpath) pretty clearly say "for GDB or LLDB", so I'm not convinced that it's only a Windows thing. In fact, given the name ("SO" for "Shared Object", whereas Windows usually uses the term "DLL"), I'd be less surprised if it was a UNIX-only thing. The docs don't mention glob stars to be supported, so I'd suggest that you try explicitly stating all the paths you want (separated by semicolons, as per documentation) without using glob stars.

So the first question for you is "Are you using GDB or LLDB? Or are you using something else like Visual Studio as the 'backend' for the debugging?"

See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_additional-symbols, which states:

> If there are additional directories where the debugger can find symbol files (for example, `.pdb` files for the Visual Studio Windows Debugger), they can be specified by adding the `additionalSOLibSearchPath` (for GDB or LLDB) or `symbolSearchPath` (for the Visual Studio Windows Debugger).

There are currently and apparently, limitations for remote debugging. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8344.

If you're curious about what GDB feature is used under the hood of the C++ extension, [Andrew Wang explains that](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8344#issuecomment-956449381)

> The `additionalSOLibSearchPath` is used to send [`set solib-search-path [Directories]`](https://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_solib-search-path) to GDB.

Interestingly, `additionalSOLibSearchPath` uses semicolons as separators, while `solib-search-path` uses colons on Linux, and semicolons on Windows. I assume the C++ extension does the necessary conversions under the hood.

Comment: I firstly tried without glob stars, but it does not change anything. I've tried with absolute and relative path, with and without the `${workspaceFolder}`, but nothing worked. I'm not in remote debbuging. I am using GDB.

Comment: @NoxFly show what you tried in your question post.